# R - Adding column to DF using loop

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I wrote a code that's looking for the min value in a specific time interval (e.g. 60 sec before and 60 sec after each observation). Now I need to write a loop that will increase the time interval by additional 60 sec. The results (min value) of new  iteration needs to be added as new column to the data frame. So summing up, with loop where i=5, 5 new columns need to be created.

I have no idea how can I add those new columns filled with results of every iteration.

I will appreciate your help.

Here is my exemplary code:

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp = ymd_hms("2017-11-24 08:00:00", "2017-11-24 08:01:00", "2017-11-24 08:02:00", "2017-11-24 08:03:00", "2017-11-24 08:04:00", "2017-11-24 08:05:00", "2017-11-24 08:06:00", "2017-11-24 08:07:00", "2017-11-24 08:08:00", "2017-11-24 08:09:00", "2017-11-24 08:10:00"),
temp=c(99.1, 98.2, 97.0, 96.5, 98.0, 97.6, 99.4, 98.2, 96.4, 99.2, 98.5))`

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

timeinterval <- 60 

for (i in 1:5) {
timeinterval <- timeinterval+60

mdf <- map(1:nrow(df), ~df[df$timestamp >= df[.x,]$timestamp-timeinterval & df$timestamp <= df[.x,]$timestamp+timeinterval,])
statdf <- map_df(mdf, ~.x %>%  
                          summarise(timestamp_to = tail(timestamp,1),
                timestamp_from = head(timestamp,1),
                                    min.temp = min(temp),
                records = n()))
}
new<-cbind(df, statdf$min.temp)
```

I suppose that cbind should be somewhere inside the loop..

Comment: I dont undestand the issue. Your dataframe has 11 samples, if you create a new column with the min value in each interval, are you going to repeat 11 times that value for each column?

Comment: The function is looking for the "rolling" min value in set of samples (the e.g 60 sec before each sample and 60 sec after, in this case there are 3 observations and the minimum value is selected) the loop increments the interval by 60 sec (so next result is minimum value of 5 observations). The goal is to add the results of each iteriation to a new column, so the final DF contains all the results obtained with increasing interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp = ymd_hms("2017-11-24 08:00:00", "2017-11-24 08:01:00", "2017-11-24 08:02:00", "2017-11-24 08:03:00", "2017-11-24 08:04:00", "2017-11-24 08:05:00", "2017-11-24 08:06:00", "2017-11-24 08:07:00", "2017-11-24 08:08:00", "2017-11-24 08:09:00", "2017-11-24 08:10:00"),
                 temp=c(99.1, 98.2, 97.0, 96.5, 98.0, 97.6, 99.4, 98.2, 96.4, 99.2, 98.5))
timeinterval <- 60
n<-5 #number of intervals

f<-function(i){
  timeinterval2 <- timeinterval*i

  mdf <- map(1:nrow(df), ~df[df$timestamp >= df[.x,]$timestamp-timeinterval2 & df$timestamp <= df[.x,]$timestamp+timeinterval2,])
  statdf <- map_df(mdf, ~.x %>%  
                     summarise(timestamp_to = tail(timestamp,1),
                               timestamp_from = head(timestamp,1),
                               min.temp = min(temp),
                               records = n()))
  return(statdf$min.temp)
}
aux<-sapply(1:n,f)
colnames(aux)<-paste("timeinterval",seq(1,n),sep="_")
cbind(df,aux)
```

Comment: I think that solves my problem, thank you very much!